# Convert json single node value STRING to OBJECT using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i convert a `json` node VALUE `STRING` to `OBJECT` using `Angularjs`. I am getting response from server *values* as *string format*. Here a node **FCLASS** is `Name` and ' **"[{ .... }]"** ' its `value` but value is string instead of array, need to remove first (**"**) and last (**"**) character and (**/**) all slashes inside `value` for converting array and object ' **[{ ... }]** '.

JSON:

```
{"FARE":[{
    "ARRV_DATE": "2016-06-25",
    "ARRV_TIME": "14:15",
    "FCLASS ": "[{\"TYPE\":\"UPPER\",\"CL\":\"M2\"},{\"TYPE\":\"UPPER\",\"CL\":\"Y2\"},{\"TYPE\":\"LOWER\",\"CL\":\"S2\"}]",
    "SEAT": 0,
    },
    {
    "ARRV_DATE": "2016-06-25",
    "ARRV_TIME": "16:20",
    "FCLASS ": "[{\"TYPE\":\"UPPER\",\"CL\":\"J2\"},{\"TYPE\":\"UPPER\",\"CL\":\"C2\"},{\"TYPE\":\"LOWER\",\"CL\":\"D2\"}]",
    "SEAT": 0,
    },
    {
    "ARRV_DATE": "2016-06-25",
    "ARRV_TIME": "19:10",
    "FCLASS ": "[{\"TYPE\":\"UPPER\",\"CL\":\"H2\"},{\"TYPE\":\"UPPER\",\"CL\":\"C2\"},{\"TYPE\":\"LOWER\",\"CL\":\"O2\"}]",
    "SEAT": 0,
    }
}]
```

`ng-repeat` isn't looping this value because its requires only `OBJECT`.

HTML(angularjs)

```
.........
<div class="col-sm-2" ng-repeat="n in f.FCLASS">
   <div>{{n.TYPE}}-{{n.CL}}</div>
</div>
.........
```

Any ideas. How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.parse to parse the json string.

try this,

```
$scope.f.FCLASS=JSON.parse(YOUR_OBJECT.FCLASS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first stringify value with

```
JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT.FCLASS);
```

then convert to JSON object with

```
JSON.parse(YOUR_OBJECT.FCLASS);
```

Because stringifying will convert to string regardless of object OR array. It will perform as expected even if there will be Array in object value.

Regards

Comment: Actually from your solution. I able to parse only single object value by defining array position. like   _console.log(JSON.stringify(fare[0].FCLASS));_

Comment: In that case i will suggest you to create filter/directive and get JSON parsed data to HTML directly.

Comment: can i do like this     <div ng-repeat='x in JSON.parse(FCLASS)'>
        {x.Cl}}
    </div>

Comment: No, so i have suggested you to use filter or directive.